# Creating Microsoft Teams App for Chat bot

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have created my own chat bot which is connected with a RESTfull API. I have some UI logic based on which I call API and get responses of the Questions.

I want to integrate this RESTfull API with Teams by creating a Teams APP and moving logic from Web UI to Teams APP UI.

Tried microsoft help from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/building-an-app but not getting any suitable tutorial  / example for it.

Any Example or tutorial will be helpful for me.

Comment: Thank you for reaching out to us We will investigate and if we require further information we will reach out. Best regards, Teams Platform

Comment: you can use microsoft teams toolkit for VSCode https://alfilatov.com/posts/how-to-create-debug-and-deploy-your-ms-teams-apps-using-vscode/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [Get started here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tutorials/get-started-dotnet-app-studio#download-the-sample) with Teams App with a simple bot And test in locally using ngrok.

There are multiple sample code [here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore). You could start with Echo Bot.

Hope it helps.